# glove: king - man + woman != queen

Tags: natural-language, word2vec

I downloaded 'glove.twitter.27B.25d.txt' from here https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/, and out of curiosity I wanted to see if `king - man + woman` does indeed approximately equal `queen`.
However, to my surprise, the cosine similarity between `king` and `queen` is: `0.9202421`, whole cosine similarity between `king - man + woman` and `queen` is `0.7530913`.

Since queen is a female king, I expected cosine similarity between `king - man + woman` and `queen` to be greater than cosine similarity between `king` and `queen`, what am I missing?

**Edit**:
If I use: glove.42B.300d.txt, my results are as expected:

`king` and `queen` sim: 0.75961757
`king - man + woman` and `queen` sim: 0.7852213

So perhaps, the issue is with glove.twitter.27B.25d.txt dataset?

Below is my code, and the values of word features:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

word_to_embeddings = dict()

with open('glove.twitter.27B.25d.txt') as f:

    for line in f:
        word = line.split()[0]
        embeddings = np.asarray(line.split()[1:], dtype='float32')
        word_to_embeddings[word] = embeddings


w = word_to_embeddings

sim_1 = cosine_similarity([w["king"]], [w["queen"]])
print(f"king and queen sim: {sim_1}")

sim_2 = cosine_similarity([w["king"] - w["man"] + w["woman"]], [w["queen"]])
print(f"king - man + woman and queen sim: {sim_2}")

print("king")
print(w["king"])
print("queen")
print(w["queen"])
print("man")
print(w["man"])
print("woman")
print(w["woman"])
```

Word features:

```
king
[-0.74501  -0.11992   0.37329   0.36847  -0.4472   -0.2288    0.70118
  0.82872   0.39486  -0.58347   0.41488   0.37074  -3.6906   -0.20101
  0.11472  -0.34661   0.36208   0.095679 -0.01765   0.68498  -0.049013
  0.54049  -0.21005  -0.65397   0.64556 ]
queen
[-1.1266   -0.52064   0.45565   0.21079  -0.05081  -0.65158   1.1395
  0.69897  -0.20612  -0.71803  -0.02811   0.10977  -3.3089   -0.49299
 -0.51375   0.10363  -0.11764  -0.084972  0.02558   0.6859   -0.29196
  0.4594   -0.39955  -0.40371   0.31828 ]
man
[ 0.37013  -0.39648  -0.021712 -0.6301   -0.3189    0.34329   0.10968
  0.4879   -0.48663   0.36837  -0.39179   0.25414  -4.9282    0.067597
  0.37147   0.36817   1.1655    0.092116 -0.87735  -0.74562   0.40903
  1.5672   -0.23879   0.24755   0.76386 ]
woman
[-9.2527e-01 -3.3879e-01 -3.2138e-01  1.4676e-01  5.2270e-01 -1.5349e-01
  1.2166e+00 -2.2389e-01 -8.6560e-02  2.8510e-01  1.8474e-01  4.2797e-01
 -4.3978e+00  2.6168e-01 -4.3044e-01 -1.1920e-03  6.6894e-01 -8.1109e-02
  5.6346e-01 -3.7477e-01  1.1786e+00  7.7134e-01 -5.2764e-01 -1.2592e+00
 -4.5112e-01]
```

Comment: What did you expect? Why? Your only question is "What am I missing?" and we can't reasonably answer that unless you explain your thinking in more detail.

Comment: @SycoraxsaysReinstateMonica, I updated my question.

Comment: could you try with glove embeddings trained with other corpus and see what you get?

Comment: @AlejandroCelis,  Thanks a lot for you suggestion. When I use glove.twitter.27B.25d.txt, the results are what I would expect. This puts things in a different perspective.

Answer (score 2):

> There are some caveats. For example, the closest value returned by the parallelogram algorithm in word2vec or GloVe embedding spaces is usually not in fact b* but one of the 3 input words or their morphological variants (i.e., cherry:red ::potato:x returns potato or potatoes instead of brown), so these must be explicitly excluded. Furthermore while embedding spaces perform well if the task involves frequent words, small distances, and certain relations (like relating countries with their capitals or verbs/nouns with their inflected forms), the parallelogram method with embeddings doesn’t work as well for other relations (Linzen 2016, Gladkova et al. 2016, Ethayarajh et al. 2019a), and indeed Peterson et al. (2020) argue that the parallelogram method is in general too simple to model the human cognitive process of forming analogies of this kind.

Reference:
6.10 of [Speech and Language Processing: An introduction to natural language processing](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ejurafsky/slp3/ed3book.pdf)